# Wifi painfully slow in Quantal

Tags: 12.10, wireless, transmission

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on the Gnome3 desktop environment.

I have a Lenovo S10-2 netbook with the following specs:

Intel® Atom™ CPU N280 @ 1.66GHz × 2 
Ram: 993.4 MiB
Graphics: unknown (On board?)
Ubuntu Partition: 14 GB
OS type: 32 bit

My Wifi connection works fine (using Network Manager) and connects automatically without any hassle. However, my transfer speeds are extremely slow.

Its weird because some days (very rarely) I get speeds upto 60 Kb/s and when downloading something via terminal, I sometimes get as much as 95-108 Kb/s.

But when I use transmission, the transfer speed for my torrent files stays painfully slow. As soon as I start downloading the torrent, the speed shoots up to 70-90 Kb/s but then right away it drops down and stays at 15-28 Kb/s.

The first time I used rtorrent and downloaded a torrent via terminal, it downloaded @ 55-70 Kb/s. But now, even rtorrent gives me the same speeds as transmission. The torrent I am downloading has plenty of seeds.

In windows I get an average speed of 50 Kb/s. BUT I HATE WINDOWS.

Also, using transmission to download torrents absolutely brings page-loading in chromium to a screeching halt.

So what should I do?

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're already getting superior speeds at certain times to any other operating system you have tried on your computer. Downloading Ubuntu will not automatically speed up your internet speed; that service is determined by your internet service provider (ISP). I would recommend moving as close to your wireless access point as possible, or even using an ethernet cord if it is not too much of a hassle.

One possibility (but this is a guess) for the apparently slower rate is that Ubuntu might update the current download speed more frequently, but there is nothing within Ubuntu that would slow download speeds. It is more likely a hardware issue, either related to your signal strength, the memory type where the download is saving, or the amount of memory allocated for Ubuntu to run.